# Google speed test, удалите css блокирующий отображение верхней части страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, оптимизация-сайтов, pagespeed-insights

Всем привет! Проверяю свой сайт на скорость загрузки через google speed test, не получается исправить следующее: "Удалите код JavaScript и CSS, блокирующий отображение верхней части страницы", а именно style.css, c js уже разобрался - скрипты подключил асинхронно, style.css подключаю через скрипт

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>");
};
```

Но тест утверждает, что style.css блокирует загрузку верхней части страницы. Подскажите, что я делаю не так!?

Answer (score -1):

Увы гугл требует, чтобы первый экран сайта грузился сразу, например стили можно прописать в head или подключить их в отдельном файле, только для первого экрана.

А ругается он, потому что сейчас у вас стили подключаются в `$(document).ready`
т.е. блокируются до полной загрузки